# Adding text and spinner options to sendEvent after button

Tags: android

Below is the full java code for my first project, I want to be able to enter a text and to choose an option from the spinner and to send them as event.

```
Please take a look below at my comment (--> ) I don't know how to do it

**package com.app.app;
import java.util.Map;
import com.appsf.appsfLib;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
          public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ 
          Button buttonreg,buttonpur,buttonemail;


        public Spinner Currency;



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appsfLib.setappsfKey("JuZ");
        appsfLib.sendTracking(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Currency = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final EditText textEntercurrency = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textEntercurrency);





        buttonreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonreg);
        buttonpur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpur);
        buttonemail =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonemail);
        buttonreg.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonpur.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonemail.setOnClickListener(this);
        sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"Loyal_Users","");


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.buttonreg:
         sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"registration",""); 
         break;
         case R.id.buttonpur:
         appsfLib.setCurrencyCode("");   **--> I want to insert in the "" an spinner options  that will be chosen from the spinner ( 5 options) called "spinner1"**
    enter code here
         sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"purchase","");   **--> I want to insert in the "" an amount of purchase that will be entered from my text field called "textEntercurrency"**
          break;
        case R.id.buttonemail:
          Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"a@a.com"});
             emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Test");
             emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose email Client..."));
             break;

        }    

             }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

          };**
```

Hope you can help me figure this out, this is my first project !!! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to insert in the "" an spinner options  that will be chosen
>   from the spinner

use `Currency.getSelectedItem()` for getting current selected item from Spinner on Button Click:

```
appsfLib.setCurrencyCode(Currency.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

> I want to insert in the "" an amount of purchase that will be entered
>   from my text field called "textEntercurrency"

use `textEntercurrency.getText()` to get text from Editext:

```
sendEvent(getApplicationContext(),"purchase",
                                  textEntercurrency.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Dude!
Just one issue, for some reason the textEntercurrency is with red line..... any ideas? you can take a look here --> 
http://c2n.me/39VH4jn

Comment: @BrianTimJesus : probably `EditText textEntercurrency` is not accessible so declare it as same way as you are doing for spinner before onCreate method

Comment: @BrianTimJesus: what error read line showing? you can get error by moving mouse cursor over red line

Comment: This is the error: http://c2n.me/39VJRsK take a look below at the pint screen:
http://c2n.me/39VJRsK

Comment: @BrianTimJesus : yes declare `textEntercurrency` outside onCreate

Comment: Almost working... just one strange error the app crash:

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.app/com.app.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 17:01:40.345: E/AndroidRuntime(31833):  at com.app.appt.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java

Comment: @BrianTimJesus: please share full log